# Bytes for Internal network addresses

Tags: networking

I have a repeating question in test in my college, which bothers me all the time.

I am translating it from another language, so bear with me:

Internal network addresses (please enter number of bytes for each field, use * if all bytes)

A class: __ __ __ __

B class: __ __ __ __

C class: __ __ __ __

I know that it should look like this:

A: ? * * *
B: ? ? * *
...

I just not sure what exactly they are asking from me, and what kind of math is needed there.

Comment: Are you sure the question says 'bytes' and not 'bits'?

Comment: That's the exact question I've asked my teacher. He laughed and said, yes, bytes.

Comment: ...Well that makes the test question even more confusing (and I'd say stupid) than it already was. Is this a standalone question or does the test have other similar ones?

Comment: So if I understand correctly you’re expected to just give an example...? However, classful networking is a thing of the past. You should request this question be removed, with appropriate respect of course.

Comment: This question is wrong on so many levels and shows a complete lack of understanding of basic networking and computer hardware. It seems the person who wrote has absolutely no idea what they are talking about. Note: I am talking about the exam question quoted by the OP, not this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the question is asking about [Classful Networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classful_network) - something which has largely been confined to history due to [CIDR (Classless Inter-Domain Routing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing).

#### TL;DR

The question isn't clear, appears to contain fundamental misunderstanding, and uses an archaic "*fact*" (which is commonly confused) for grading students. I'd push back.

---

As they are asking about "*internal network addresses*", then it's possible they are referring to the reserved address spaces for [Private Network Addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) (however I don't think this is their intention):

- `10.0.0.0/8` - one Class A network
- `172.16.0.0/12` - 16x Class B networks, back to back
- `192.168.0.0/16` - 256x Class C networks

---

The question goes on to say "*please enter number of bytes for each field*"... An IPv4 address is a 32-bit address, that is broken into four 8-bit (1 byte / octet) chunks and written in decimal. Let's presume that by "*... number of **bytes** ...*" they actually mean "*... number of **bits** ...*" - especially as there are four "*fields*" given.

> He laughed and said, yes, bytes

[image: rolleyes]

---

In this case, the question could probably be better worded as below (though it's still an odd question to ask):

> Write the number of bits of each octet that is used to represent the network prefix.

Huh... "*network prefix"*?

That `/8`, `/12` or `/16` at the end of the reserved address spaces above is one method of representing a [subnet mask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork#Determining_the_network_prefix). Another representation that you may be more familiar with is a value such as `255.255.255.0` (which equates to `/24`).

- The `/x` notation states "*x bits are used for the network address*"
- The `255.255.255.0` notation states "*this is the mask used for the network address*".

`255.255.255.0` or `/24` can be written out in full, in binary as:

```
dec      255      255      255        0  
bin   11111111 11111111 11111111 00000000
```

#### Class A

So, given that a Class A network is `/8` (or `255.0.0.0`), it could be written as:

```
dec      255        0        0        0  
bin   11111111 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

The answer I'd give would be: `8, 0, 0, 0`.

#### Class B

So, given that a Class B network is `/16` (or `255.255.0.0`), it could be written as:

```
dec      255      255       0        0  
bin   11111111 11111111 00000000 00000000
```

The answer I'd give would be: `8, 8, 0, 0`.

#### Class C

So, given that a Class C network is `/24` (or `255.255.255.0`), it could be written as:

```
dec      255      255      255        0  
bin   11111111 11111111 11111111 00000000
```

The answer I'd give would be: `8, 8, 8, 0`.

---

Conversely, if what they actually wanted to ask was:

> Write the number of bits of each octet that is used to represent the **host address**.

I'd use the following responses - note the bits are inverted from the subnet mask to produce the "*host address mask*".

#### Class A

So, given that a Class A network is `/8` (or `255.0.0.0`), it could be written as:

```
dec      255        0        0        0  
bin   11111111 00000000 00000000 00000000  <== subnet mask
bin   00000000 11111111 11111111 11111111  <== host address mask
```

The answer I'd give would be: `0, 8, 8, 8`.

#### Class B

So, given that a Class B network is `/16` (or `255.255.0.0`), it could be written as:

```
dec      255      255        0        0  
bin   11111111 11111111 00000000 00000000
bin   00000000 00000000 11111111 11111111  <== host address mask
```

The answer I'd give would be: `0, 0, 8, 8`.

#### Class C

So, given that a Class C network is `/24` (or `255.255.255.0`), it could be written as:

```
dec      255      255      255        0  
bin   11111111 11111111 11111111 00000000
bin   00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111  <== host address mask
```

The answer I'd give would be: `0, 0, 0, 8`.

Comment: Good anser according to Cisco. For the rest of the world Class A used to be n.h.h.h, class B n.n.h.h (so NOT 172.16/12 as on some Cisco websites) and class C n.n.n.h/24 (so 255.255.255.0 if you prefer that over /24).

Comment: I was touch is in the 'rest of wold way'. Namy books agreed. Then I hit a Cisco website. Some of those (but not all). disagreed. Heck of a mess. :)

Comment: Sjees, I answered to quickly. s/touch/thought.   s/namy/many/.   Agrh! Coffee time.

Comment: @Hennes: For class B, both /12 and /16 are correct in different ways. Individual "class B" networks were always /16's, however, the _entire reserved range_ for private use is a /12 because it was a chunk of 16 class-B's, therefore Cisco is correct here when talking about RFC1918 ranges. (And likewise, 192.168.0.0/16 is correct because it was originally a chunk of 256 class-C's, even though each class-C was a /24.)

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up @grawity - I think I've been round this one before... Hopefully my edits make sense.

Comment: Typo alert: 192.18.0.0/16 in the answer should be 192.168.0.0/16